# Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type. error while getting response when trying to Upload file in Box Storage

Tags: winforms

When i am trying to upload files in `Box Storage` using api provided by Box but at response time i am getting this error

```
public static void UploadFileRequest(string FolderID, string accesstoken)
        {

            string boundary = string.Format("----------------------------{0}", DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x"));
            string filename="C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Text.txt";
            HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content");
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

            string hh = "\"filename=@\"" + filename + "\" "+";"+"";
            hh += "parent_id=\"" + FolderID + "\"";
            string kj = string.Format(("filename=@" + filename));

            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(hh);

            httpWReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken);
            httpWReq.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

            string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the Box API, I will assume that the upload should be a POST operation, so you will need to specify the correct HTTP method on your request, before sending it:

```
httpWReq.Method = "POST";
```

The [`Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.method.aspx) property defaults to `"GET"`, and GET operations does not normally have a body..

Comment: Fredrik you are right , i was missing POST method there .. but still no response for me . I think there is problem in body format .

Comment: Getting error in the response (400) , somewhere doing mistake in the body message 

            string bodymessage = string.Format("filename=@{0}&parent_id={1}", filename, FolderID);
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(bodymessage);

            //getting error in below line StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }

Comment: Are you writing your bytes to the request stream before calling `GetResponse()`?

Comment: Yes i am doing it  byte[] postBytes = ascii.GetBytes(postData.ToString());httpWReq.Method = "POST";
            httpWReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer RWy0TukUsLY8jyFOuiQCp8IzPGO4F0r3");
            httpWReq.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            httpWReq.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
            using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            }

Comment: @user3463612 as said, I am not familiar with the Box API. The HTTP status 400 indicates that the communication is OK, but Box can't make sense of the stuff that you send, so you need to verify exactly what you are sending them, and exactly what they expect to get.

Comment: Resolved the problem , was doing mistake in passing the body .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution , as C# accepts bytes format and then any Upload is done , i was missing that .. hope it helps

private void UploadBoxFile(string Filename)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content") as HttpWebRequest;
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer < Access Token >");
            req.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\"d174f29b-6def-47db-8519-3da38b21b398\"";

```
        string Content = GetFormatedData(Filename);

        req.ContentLength = Content.Length;
        using (Stream Writer = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            Writer.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Content), 0, Content.Length);
        }

        req.GetResponse();
    }

    private string GetFormatedData(string Filename)
    {
        StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
        string Id = "d174f29b-6def-47db-8519-3da38b21b398";

        build.AppendLine("--" + Id);
        build.AppendLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"hello1.txt\"; name=\"filename\"");
        build.AppendLine("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        build.AppendLine();

        string FileContent = "This is a sample text";
        build.AppendLine(FileContent);

        build.AppendLine("--" + Id);
        build.AppendLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"folder_id\"");
        build.AppendLine();

        build.AppendLine("0");
        build.AppendLine("--" + Id + "--");


        return build.ToString();
    }
```

Thanks..